# Anatomically Correct Murlocs

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, creature-design, mythical-creatures, sea-creatures

So Murlocs. I'm referencing Murlocs from World of Warcraft since I never actually found any other novels or games that have them.

Described as a bipedal, amphibious, intelligent, aggressive[Still capable of negotiations] race residing along coastlines, lakeshores, and riverbeds.

Murlocs have

- bulbous bodies
- large mouths filled with sharp fangs
- Slime-coated skin
- height of around 3-6feet[but are usually hunched down]

How might they have evolved?

[Anatomically Correct Series](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798)

[MURLOCS](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Murloc)

[image: Murloc]

Comment: What do you mean "still capable of negotiations?" Mrhrglrhgllglglhrlgl!

Comment: Murlocs apparently speak Nerglish!! And it seems that a group of them have actually communicated with the other races so I'm just saying that they are not gonna go like Mmmmuudeerrr

Comment: Aaaaaughibbrgubugbugrguburgle! Fish on legs...

Comment: Catching up on old questions : This questions is asking about a clearly defined 3rd party world without showing some clear worldbuilding purpose. Besides (and my reason to close), the issue "how might it have evolved?" is very broad and lack some prior worldbuilding research; It would have been more focused to ask about a specific part of murloc-like creatures, for instance "how can they reach tool usage tech if we took frogs as the starting point?" or "how do they communicate between each others *and* other species with only mumbles?".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because under current rules questions about 3rd party worlds are off topic. Normally we leave old questions alone but since this has entered the review queue it should be held to the same standard as any other question in the queue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Murlocs are basically carnivorous frog so you can start from here.

Initially, you have frogs in an environment with mixed water and land but with little amount of bugs, so classical frog hunting method of capturing bugs with theirs tongues and switch to hunting like small predator and evolve to a jaw with small teeth.

Next, murlocs begin to need to hunt bigger prey due to a lack of small comestible prey. In order to be able to kill taller animals, murlocs are forced to hunt in group, thus developing communications abilities and improved intelligence.

Over time, murlocs grow bigger due to better feeding, this increase in size allow a better brain, that lead to increased intelligence and therefore better hunting tactics that allow to kill bigger prey improving the available food, continuing the cycle.

Eventually, murlocs reach the limit in size of 3-6feet due to the available prey.

Comment: Many frogs already have teeth (pacman, african bullfrog) and eat non-bugs. In fact, frogs tend to eat basically anything that moves and fits in their mouths; they don't have the best eye sight, so they'll chomp on a stick that waves in front of their faces and release when they realize _ewww... stick..._

Comment: sounds like a murloc to me